# Unsupported MIME type

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I try to take a screenshot when my test fails. I can take a screenshot on the ios device but not on the android device.
It fails with the error of:

`[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unsupported MIME type: 
        at Jimp.throwError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/jimp/index.js:82:43)
        at Jimp.parseBitmap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/jimp/index.js:307:31)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/jimp/index.js:200:29
        at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)`

it used to work on appium 1.4.16. now i am on appium 1.6.0
this is my code:

```
    public static String captureScreenshot(AppiumDriver driver, String screenshotName){
        try {
            TakesScreenshot ts = driver;
            File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            String dest = "/Users/automation/Desktop/Reports/" +screenshotName+".png";
            File destination = new File(dest);
            FileUtils.copyFile(source,destination);
            System.out.println("Screenshot was taken");
            return dest;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.report("Exception while taking the screenshot");
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

any idea how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: It could be because you use latest major version and this could be Appium bug. This solution is working fine on Appium v1.5.3.

Comment: yes, it's actual for 1.6.4-beta too. I downgraded appium to 1.5.3 and all working ok